# MySQL Insert Select based on existing values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a method which will create duplicate (default) values for each new project we create within our task management system. At the moment it runs multiple loops based on a `default`=1 SELECT query and then inserts new rows based on the default values. These values must be duplicated on a new project (not the same).

I personally feel it's using a lot of unneccesary overhead and can be tuned to work more efficiently, esspecially looking at INSERT SELECT queries, but i am not sure how to approach this.

```
 public function copyProductDefaults($productID, $userID) {
    // Run loop for tasks categories:
    $sql = "SELECT `name`,`description` FROM `tasks_categories` WHERE `default`=1";
    $rows = $this->get($sql, array());
    foreach ($rows AS $row) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tasks_categories` (`name`,`description`,`product_id`,`user_id`,`default`,`create_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
        $this->insert($sql, array($row['name'], $row['description'], $productID, $userID,0));
    }

    // Run loop for tasks types:
    $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `tasks_types` WHERE `default`=1";
    $rows = $this->get($sql, array());
    foreach ($rows AS $row) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tasks_types` (`name`,`product_id`,`user_id`,`default`,`create_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
        $this->insert($sql, array($row['name'], $productID, $userID,0));
    }

    // Run loop for tasks statuses:
    $sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `tasks_statuses` WHERE `default`=1";
    $rows = $this->get($sql, array());
    foreach ($rows AS $row) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tasks_statuses` (`name`,`product_id`,`user_id`,`default`,`create_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
        $this->insert($sql, array($row['name'], $productID, $userID,0));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: This is better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
INSERT INTO task_categories (name,description,product_id,user_id,`default`,create_date)
    SELECT name,description,?,?,0,now() FROM task_categories WHERE `default`=1
```

(and the same for the other two).